# Scaffolding Using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having trouble using Scaffolding in ASP.NET MVC 3.
My models are good and the database generated is also good but i am wondering if the scaffolding in MVC 3 is works for many to many relationships?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Scott Hanselman and Steven Sanderson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813440/stuck-with-asp-net-mvc-3-0-scaffolding-in-case-of-many-to-many-relationship), many-to-many relationships are outside the scope of what scaffolding handles natively. Follow the link to see what Steven Sanderson recommends as an alternative.