# Many to many relationships in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm using **MVC 3** with **Razor** and **Entity Framework** for an assignment.

So far, I have been using scaffolds to create a basic CRUD page for all my models.

Two of the models I have are Musicians and Sessions, this is a many-to-many relationship (there is a pivot table for them in the database, but not in the models).

Basically, I need some way of assigning musicians to sessions, but I've noticed that all my properties get populated by the Razor tag, `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeProperty)`, but how can I get this to work with a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look here:

[stuck with asp.net mvc 3.0 Scaffolding in case of many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813440/stuck-with-asp-net-mvc-3-0-scaffolding-in-case-of-many-to-many-relationship)

By default, ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't scaffold many-to-many relationships. As mentioned in that link, your best option is to scaffold your Session or Musician and then hand-code the selection of the other model in each view.